# Семантика слова работающий

Tags: лексика, семантика

Каково значение слова работающий? Есть определение слова работник, рабочий, а определение слова работающий не нашла. Есть ли какие-то контекстуальные ограничения в использовании этого слова, или его можно рассматривать как синоним к слову работник(то есть они взаимозаменяемы в контексте)? Например: *Расстройство здоровья работающих/работников под действием вредных веществ.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текстах, связанных, к примеру,  с охраной здоровья, **работники, работающие, работающее население ― это синонимы** с общим значением  "те, кто работает".

Например:  Одним из наиболее важных индикаторов здоровья общества является состояние здоровья его **работников**. Неблагоприятные условия труда почти во всех отраслях промышленности и сельского хозяйства — главная причина ухудшения здоровья **работающих**. [Здоровье работающих | lrkb.ru](http://lrkb.ru/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5/)

**В других случаях (в различных сочетаниях) эти слова не заменяют друг друга**, например: отличный работник, научный работник, работник тяжелой промышленности.

Answer (score 1):

"**Работающий**" - человек, занимающийся трудовой деятельностью (характеристика *занятости*).
"**Работник**" - человек, *работающий по найму* (отношение к работодателю - организации или индивидуальному нанимателю); в расширеном понимании (чему человек служит) - в составе словосочетаний вида "работник такой-то сферы" - принадлежность работающего конкретной области трудовой деятельности.

В вашем примере выбор слова зависит от содержания и направленности текста. Если речь идёт о конкретном предприятии, где выявлены нарушения, то правильнее говорить о "*работниках*", поскольку юридические последствия связаны с соблюдением прав людей, работающих *в отношениях найма*, т. е. "**работников**" этого предприятия. Если же это статистическое исследование, не затрагивающее вопросы отношений с работодателями, а например, выявляющее в некоем регионе повышенную заболеваемость (от вредных веществ в местной атмосфере) людей *занятых* в сравнении с детьми и пенсионерами, то говорить нужно о "**работающих**".